# Sitecore: efficient way to use LINQ to compare against an ID

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a LINQ query retrieving a list of , such as this:

```
var results = SearchContext.GetQueryable<Person>()
  .Where(i => i.Enabled)
  .Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Person")
  .Random(6);
```

Each object of type "Person" has a "Location" field which is also a Glass mapped item, and hence has an ID; I would like to only select items whose Location has a specific ID.

How can I go about doing this in an **efficient** manner?

EDIT: I should probably clarify that I am unable to perform this comparison, efficiently or not. Because the GUID is an object and I cannot perform ToString in a LINQ query, I am unable to only pick the items whose Location item has a specific ID. Any clues on how this could be achieved?

EDIT 2: Adding the clause

```
.Where(i => i.Location.Id == this.Id)
```

Doesn't work, for... some reason, as I'm unable to debug what LINQ "sees". If I convert the other ID I'm comparing it against to string this way:

```
var theOtherID = this.Id.ToString("N");
```

Then it works with this LINQ line:

```
.Where(i => i["Location"].Contains(theOtherID))
```

I still have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to include a separate property on `Person` that is ignored by Glass mapper, but can be used in searches:

```
[SitecoreIgnore]
[Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexField("location")]
public Sitecore.Data.ID LocationID { get; set; }
```

You can use this in your search as follows:

```
Sitecore.Data.ID locationId = Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(stringOrGuid);
var results = SearchContext.GetQueryable<Person>()
  .Where(i => i.Enabled)
  .Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Person")
  .Where(i => i.LocationID == locationId)
  .Random(6);
```

I think the efficiency of using multiple where clauses vs. conditionals is debatable. They will likely result in the same Lucene query being performed. I would prefer readability over optimization in this instance, but that's just me.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I am unable to perform this comparison, efficiently or not. Because the GUID is an object and I cannot perform ToString in a LINQ query, I am unable to only pick the items whose Location item has a specific ID. Any clues on how this could be achieved?

Comment: I don't see why you need to call ToString(). You should be able to compare the GUID or ID directly. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Also, what version of Sitecore are you using here? Are you using ContentSearch or something else?

Comment: 7.2. The problem is that the ID is on a "child" object - a Location associated to my Person, and direct comparison didn't work. I eventually found an odd solution, where all seemingly intuitive solutions didn't cut it. Will update my question accordingly, but will still consider your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a more efficient methods than using a simple `where` statement like in:

```
var results = SearchContext.GetQueryable<Person>()
    .Where(i => i.Enabled && i.TemplateName == "Person" && 
         i.Location != null && i.Location.Id == 1)
    .Random(6);
```

Keep in mind that if you use the `&&` statement instead of a `where` for each parameter, you reduce the complexity of the algorithm.

You could also use an [Inverse Navigation Property](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html) on `Location` to a `virtual ICollection<Person>` and then be able to do this:

```
var results = SearchContext.GetQueryable<Location>()
    .Where(i => i.Id == 1 && i.Persons.Where(p => p.Enabled && p.TemplateName == "Person").Any())
    .Random(6);
```

The first option would still be the most efficient, because the second one uses `sub-queries`. But it is worth knowing you can do your search the other way.

Comment: Thank you.
The point is, Location.Id is a Sitecore Guid, and I cannot use .ToString() inside Linq.

Any idea on how I can make this comparison?

Comment: Not quite there - I still need to return a list of "Person", but I need to check on the ID of the "Location" field that each Person has.

Comment: Try Derek Hunziker's solution for your `Sitecore Guid` problem.

Comment: This solution won't work because the query parser won't know to convert i.Location.ID to Location. Use the first answer to achieve what you need.